# Proof with families of sets and cartesian product

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory

Let $I$ be a non-empty set, let $\{A_{i}\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of sets indexed by $I$ and let $B$ be a set.

(1)Prove that $B \times (\cup_{i \in I}A_{i}) = \cup_{i \in I}(B\times A_{i})$.

(2)Prove that $B \times (\cap_{i \in I}A_{i}) = \cap_{i \in I}(B\times A_{i})$.

Not real to sure how to prove these statements. I can get it to where an arbitrary x is in B and an arbitrary y is in $A_i$ for some/all $i \in I$ but don't know how to prove that y is in the union/intersection. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For (1), start with $(x,y)\in B\times(\cup_{i\in I} A_i)$. This means that $x\in B$ and $y\in\cup_{i\in I}A_i$, which implies $x\in B$ and that there exists $i_0\in I$ such that $y\in A_{i_0}$. Hence $(x,y)\in B\times A_{i_0}$, which proves $(x,y)\in\cup_{i\in I}(B\times A_i)$.

For the reverse direction, try working backwards from this.

Problem (2) is similar, but remember that an element $x$ is in the intersection of a family if and only if $x$ is in each element of the family.

Please comment if you get stuck.